# Installation of Eclipse Plugin fails in Helios

Tags: eclipse, helios

While trying to install Subclipse into ODM Enterprise (Helios based) the following error appears

> An error occurred while installing the items session context
>   was:(profile=SDKProfile,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install,
>   operand=null --> [R]com.ibm.icu.source 4.2.1.v20100412,
>   action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.AddSourceBundleAction).
>   The artifact file for osgi.bundle,com.ibm.icu.source,4.2.1.v20100412
>   was not found.

this happens regardless which Installation is selected (Online/Offline Update Site/ Dropins). Subclipse does not require this plugin.

Comment: What r u trying to install? Which plugin? What are you trying to achieve? What is your question?

Comment: It is regardless what you try to install. Both JADClipse and Subclipse produced this error and it disappeared after running Eclipse as Admin. This was verified on multiple boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. After reading [Forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/eclim-user/qA9vSHn-sPc) I looked in the right direction. This error is completely misleading. In my case it was, that the eclipse directory was owned by admin and I couldn't write. After running Eclipse with admin privileges it worked as expected.